# Find multiple words in a long word and sort the results by relevance

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am doing queries to a database that stores one, very long, word in each of the records. The are no spaces, no special characters, only ualpha. Right now I am using the LIKE keyword to look for records that contain all of the words from my input. I would like the script to show me results with the highest relevance first.

So for example, I type in "be me if". This script should first return records that contain all of those words, like this:

"XSF**BE**NSU**ME**POPKL**IF**"

Then it would show those that contain only two of those words and then finally those that contain only one of those words.

I tried using "ORDER BY CASE" and giving points to the best matches, like this:

```
 - ORDER BY CASE
 - WHEN `code` LIKE '%word1%' AND `code` LIKE '%word2%' THEN 1
 - WHEN `code` LIKE '%word1%' THEN 2
 - ELSE 3 END;
```

It worked but when given more than three words the server crashed because it had to browse through almost **4 million** records and simply couldn't handle it.

I tried fulltext search after that but it doesn't allow me to search for partial words, only prefixes.

**Is there any way to achieve what I am looking for?**

Comment: Seems like a good use for full text indexes. This is exactly what they were made for.

Comment: if you would not jam your "XSFBENSUMEPOPKLIF" together, and do the full text route, this wouldn't be an issue. Plus the `like` solutions will be doing table scans

Comment: @Drew What are you talking about, I didn't jam anything together, this is output from a decrypting machine, it has to be that way because the machine doesn't know where it should put spaces.

Comment: I guess I am talking about something that wasn't made very clear in the question. Please forgive my transgression

Comment: @Drew If something wasn't clear in the question then you can't just assume that I did something. It's not my job to say what I DIDN'T do because that would require me to write EVERYTHING that I didn't do in order to protect myself from people just assuming that I did something.

Comment: well if you can't plop some spaces in there, or are unwilling, then you are in for a world of continued pain

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the values.  MySQL treats booleans as integers, so you can do:

```
order by ((code like '%word1%') +
          (code like '%word2%') +
          (code like '%word3%')
         ) desc
```

EDIT:

Of course, this should be after a `where` clause:

```
where code like '%word1%' or code like '%word2%' or code like '%word3%'
```

Comment: but wouldn't this require as much processing power as my "order by case" example did?

Comment: I don't see what a more complicated `order by` clause would cause your server to crash.